# Как узнать какие есть git репозитории на устройстве?

Tags: git, поиск, репозиторий

Как узнать какие есть git репозитории на устройстве? И, желательно, как узнать в каких папках находятся эти репозитории.

//Конечно есть вариант установить на Windows приложение Everything и сделать поиск ".git" по всему ПК, но это не то, что я бы хотел.

Comment: Только так, скорее всего.

Answer (score 2):

Зависит от желаемого результата. Может `dir .git /b/s` будет достаточно?

Comment: а как быть с голыми репозиториями, как быть с переменной окружения GIT_DIR и другими??

Answer (score 2):

Git - очень [конфигурируемая система](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/Git-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%83%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%8B) контроля версий. Это значит, что нет простого способа детектировать, является ли произвольно выбранный каталог Git репозиторием или нет. Скорее всего, вам придётся просмотреть *каждый* файл в системе на предмет наличия [магических сигнатур Git](https://github.com/file/file/blob/master/magic/Magdir/revision#L33).

По идее такая команда, будучи запущенной в Bash, произведёт поиск файлов (по всей ФС), которые могут иметь отношение к Git.

```
find / -type f -exec bash -c 'head -n1 "$1" | grep -qE $'"'(^# v2 git bundle$)|(^PACK)|(^\377tOc)|(^DIRC)'" - {} \; -print
```

Comment: И давно в Windows появился grep?

Comment: windows? ну те, кто этим пользуется, говорят, что там есть git'овая консолька...

Comment: Этот скрипт ищет что угодно, но только не репозитории))
Запустил в git bash на windows
https://i.imgur.com/iO0hDGZ.png

Comment: @ЕгорСпириади, пришлось усложнить команду - так, надеюсь, будет меньше ложных срабатываний